# Image in ListTile

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

How to add a photo to a listtile that would have the height equal to the full height of the listtile and width for example 200?

```
    Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
             minWidth: 80,
             minHeight: 80,
             ),
        child: Image.network('https://d-pt.ppstatic.pl/k/r/1/59/d4/5cb1dbc30ec6d_p.jpg?1555262447', width: 120, height: 120),),
        title: Text('Three-line ListTile'),
        subtitle: Text(
          'A sufficiently long subtitle warrants three lines.'
        ),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
        isThreeLine: true,
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Card(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Image.network(
            'https://d-pt.ppstatic.pl/k/r/1/59/d4/5cb1dbc30ec6d_p.jpg?1555262447',
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Three-line ListTile'),
            subtitle:
                Text('A sufficiently long subtitle warrants three lines.'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
            isThreeLine: true,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

And then adjust the size of the image based on the flex property.